# A little help need with JSON format (text from prismic output to Angular)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to get a Angular based frontend working, but i am having difficulty working with this format. It's html tags are in JSON format and am wondering how to output them (In Javascript/Angular). Here is a snippet (hope it works):

```
spans": [ { "start": 63, "end": 70, "type": "strong" } ] }, { "type": "paragraph", "text": "Notice how the tag bar transforms into a formatting toolbar when you're writing in this editor. Now, this might look like a wysiwyg, but this is actually not your average wysiwyg, as it stores structured content, and not HTML. It allows you to build your content in better ways as you type it, making it easy for you to present it in various ways later.", "spans": [ { "start": 41, "end": 59, "type": "strong" } ] }
```

Anybody has any experience with this? I would like to know how to "crawl" this JSON document to output (for example the spans) to HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: You've only pasted part of the JSON string. As it stands at the moment, the above is not a valid JSON.

Comment: What you want to do? show example.

Comment: Allright, gotta figure this out myself :-)